# Mysql Transaction and Locking

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, locking, adodb

I am testing the transaction in MySql.
I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtransaction1` (
  `a` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE `testtransaction2` (
  `a` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

After that I am running the script:

```
$conn->StartTrans ();
try {
    $conn->Execute("insert into testtransaction1(a) values (1),(2)");


    sleep(5);

    $conn->Execute("insert into testtransaction2 select * from testtransaction1 where b is null");

    $conn->Execute("update testtransaction1 set b=100 where b is null");
    echo "Ran insert into testtransaction2 select * from testtransaction1 where b is null";
    $out=$conn->CompleteTrans ($autoComplete=true);

    var_dump($out);
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
}
```

So,What I m doing is running the same script twice within few seconds gap.To test if transaction locks the table.

What I am seeing is only the first transaction is complete and second fails.

Please let me know why is this happening..

Comment: Let's clarify this a bit. You run the script you've written twice with a short pause between, the first one var_dumps `true` and the second one - `false`? BTW, `$conn->CompleteTrans($autoComplete=true)` can be safely rewritten to just `$conn->CompleteTrans()`, as `true` is the default param.

Comment: yeah..I ran the script twice with a short pause and one return true and second one false..

Comment: ok..the reason i see can be "Lock wait timeout exceeded"